# Разделение GET запроса

Tags: php, get

Подскажите пожалуйста как разделить данные из GET запроса на 2 отдельные переменные?

```
'edit_product.php?id=197&name=seven'
```

чтоб получилось:
'$a = 197'
'$b = seven'

Comment: `$a = $_GET['id'];` и `$b = $_GET['name'];`

Comment: если у вас просто строка со ссылкой, то `parse_url()` + `parse_str()`

Answer (score 0):

Из url строки извлечь нужные переменные получилось так:

```
$parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
parse_str( $parts['query'] , $query );
echo $query['id'];
echo $query['name'];
```